# How To: onClick/onChange for a <select>'s <option> in a child component

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to have a child component which rendered only an `<option>` tag to trigger the `onChange` of it's parent `<select>` ?

I ask because I've tried `onClick` and `onChange` on the the child `<option>` and it seems to be aloof to them.

The idea is a parent React component that looks like this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <ChildOption onClick={this.handleChange}
    </select>
  );
}
```

and the ChildOption component like this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <option onClick={this.handleClick} />
  );
}
```

The full code for this issue is here in a CodePen (pretend it's returning an array of `<option>`s:

- http://codepen.io/mikeumus/pen/BpzeYO?editors=0010

Real world code here in Cloud9:

- https://ide.c9.io/mikeumus/ca-blinds#imports/plugins/included/product-detail-simple/client/components/variantList.js:205

Comment: `onclick` for `option`s is very poorly supported by browsers. May I ask why you need this behaviour?

Comment: I would advise you to handling the data on the select onChange and doing the option onClick work through it based on option value.

Comment: Is `handleClick` a thing in `ChildOption`?

Comment: @DavinTryon, yes it's in the CodePen and C9.

@FabianSchultz, how to add an event to just a lone `<option>` in a child component then?

@FabioCosta, I may be misunderstanding what you're saying but from what I've tried, `onClick` nor `onChange` work with React's events for an `<option>` element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have a child component that only renders the `option` tag. You actually don't need to add an event handler to the `option` tag. The `select` `onChange` event get called automatically once an `option` tag is clicked (passing it's value with it).

See the example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBzzWr?editors=0010

Comment: Very cool but why in my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/mikeumus/pen/BpzeYO?editors=0010) above does the parent `onChange` not fire?

Comment: Your `onChange` event does not fire because there is only one `option`. Therefore, there is a never a change event because the value is always the same. If you add another `option` then your parent event will be called.